# What will happen if I attempt a contactless payment over the advertised limit?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, contactless

I work at a food retailer and we accept contactless payments. I've noticed that our card machines still display the Contactless and Apple Pay symbols when a bill is above the limit for contactless payments.

Presumably this means that the card machine will still read a contactless card; what will happen if a bill is above the advertised limit for contactless payments (currently £30 in the U.K)?

I've asked and apparently nobody has ever attempted to pay with contactless above the limit in our branch, and as a result nobody seems to know what happens (management do not seem to know either).

Some things I can think of that could possibly happen:

- The advertised limit is a 'soft' limit- anything above will go through but is not protected by the bank's/payment provider's anti-fraud policies;
- The card machine immediately rejects the payment;
- The card machine refuses to read the card although the 'contactless' symbol is displayed;
- Payment is attempted, but the bank declines the transaction

What will actually happen?

Comment: I would just grab an item over the limit and try.  If it works, you know what happens and can return the item, if not you know how/why it failed.

Comment: @Joe I was asking in general, therefore the united-kingdom tag is not appropiate.

Comment: payment systems, norms, and laws are quite different from country to country.

Comment: @cybermonkey There is no general rule - and in fact, the 30 pound limit is only in the united kingdom.  I think your question would need to be closed as 'too broad' if it weren't specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For contactless cards, it seems that it will prompt to insert the chip card (so it can do a normal chip+pin verification) and/or enter the PIN, probably depending on the card issuer and/or the terminal software.  See [this FAQ](http://www.nationwide.co.uk/support/payments-and-transfers/contactless/frequently-asked-questions#xtab:is-there-a-limit-on-the-value-of-goods-i-can-purchase-with-my-contactless-card) for example.

For Android or Apple pay, it depends on the POS software.  If the software supports it, it may simply allow it even at a higher limit; [Apple pay allows any amount](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204906) with authentication (for all transactions), while [Android pay has a limit of £100](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/everything-you-need-to-know-about-android-pay-in-the-uk-1321615), and will require a device authentication (fingerprint or device PIN) over £30.  But some software may still enforce a lower limit (£30 or even £20 if it's really old).